# sfBBCodeParserPlugin, problems with partial

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, partial, symfony-plugins

I use symfony 1.4.8 , and [sfBBCodeParserPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfBBCodeParserPlugin/1_0_2?tab=plugin_contribute) 
It works , but I have problem with partial.

My IndexSuccess

```
include_partial('post/list', array('voice_posts' => $voice_posts)) ?>
```

In _list.php

```
 echo $bb_parser->getRawValue()->qparse($voice_post->getDescription());
```

And I have error

**Notice: Undefined variable: bb_parser in...**

according to the readme I added in action.class

```
 public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
 ....
 $this->bb_parser = new sfBBCodeParser(); 
  }
```

In ShowSuccess I do not use partial and all work fine.
ShowSuccess.php

```
 echo  $bb_parser->getRawValue()->qparse($voice_post->getDescription())
```

action.class

```
 public function executeShow(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
 $this->bb_parser = new sfBBCodeParser();
    ...
  }
```

p.s Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget you send to the partial the **bb_parser**:

```
include_partial('post/list', array('voice_posts' => $voice_posts, 'bb_parser' => $bb_parser))
```

Remember that the variables used in partials (unless they're global) must be sent when you're defining it.